# Notify Socket to send message after database update

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, ws

I'm using ws on nodejs currently to link to WebSockets on the frontend.

I'd like to emit a message to all websockets with `X` id when a database change happens.

Is there a way to have the `ws` listen to database changes? OR Is there a way to notify the `ws` that there's been a database update?